# Need suggestion to use alternate for Faststring.pas in delphi

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-11-alexandria

I have converted code from **Delphi 6 32-bit** to **Delphi 11 64-bit**, and in the source code we have used [Fast String](https://github.com/dekked/subtitleworkshop/blob/master/SubtitleWorkshop/Units/FastStrings.pas) to use the `FastReplace()` and `FastPos()` functions.

I have tried to compile the `FastStrings.pas` unit file using **Delphi 11 64-bit**, but it raises a compilation error as it contains `asm` code. So, I have replaced the `FastPos()` function to `Pos()` to resolve the compilation error.

What could be an exact alternate method to including the `FastPos()` function that has the same functionality?

```
//The first thing to note here is that I am passing the SourceLength and FindLength
//As neither Source or Find will alter at any point during FastReplace there is
//no need to call the LENGTH subroutine each time !
function FastPos(const aSourceString, aFindString : string; const aSourceLen, aFindLen, StartPos : Integer) : Integer;
var
  JumpTable: TBMJumpTable;
begin
  //If this assert failed, it is because you passed 0 for StartPos, lowest value is 1 !!
  Assert(StartPos > 0);
  if aFindLen < 1 then begin
    Result := 0;
    exit;
  end;
  if aFindLen > aSourceLen then begin
    Result := 0;
    exit;
  end;

  MakeBMTable(PChar(aFindString), aFindLen, JumpTable);
  Result := Integer(BMPos(PChar(aSourceString) + (StartPos - 1), PChar(aFindString),aSourceLen - (StartPos-1), aFindLen, JumpTable));
  if Result > 0 then
    Result := Result - Integer(@aSourceString[1]) +1;
end;
```

I have used the `StringReplace()` function instead of `FastReplace()` and it works fine in Delphi 64-bit.

Kindly, provide any solution to implement `FastPos()` functionality in Delphi 11 64-bit.

Comment: You may just use the standard StringReplace and Pos functions and postpone the fast approach for when it is actually needed. Perhaps the current intrinsic routines are already fast enough.

Comment: The standard string manipulation functions from Delphi have been reworked in the past to become much more faster then the ones back from D6, so the FastStrings unit isn't needed anymore. In contrast those function could be even slower now then the ones shipping with Delphi!

Comment: Latest Delphi version uses the FastCode `Pos()` pascal version for 64 bit compilation. The 32 bit is already the FastCode `Pos()` version but in asm. It is hard to get faster implementations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20947429 see the update at the end of this answer regarding D11 Alexandria!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `Pos()` and it's working fine as required.